# Is there a standard way of passing data to a back-end program of a web application? If so what is it?

Tags: web-applications, user-input, backend

I'm currently creating a web application that takes user data from a form, posts that to a PHP script and from there the PHP runs an executable on the server with the form data as the arguments to the executable.

To clarify, I have an executable file that does calculations based on what the user inputs. Once I have the form data in the back-end, PHP is used to run:

```
./myExecutable arg1 arg2 arg3 ...
```

Where the outputs are returned to the PHP and then finally, to the user.

My question is:

**Is there a standard (better?) way to handle a situation like this, where there's a large server-side program that's required to deal with user input.**

I'm new to web apps but some of the thoughts that have crossed my mind are:

- Is there a way to have the same result without using an executable? (How do huge applications like google maps handle the back-end portion?)
- If an executable is really the ideal way of going about this, what happens if I have, say 50 arguments? Could I pass in all 50 from the command line, or would it be smarter to use files containing the input data (or is there an even better way)?

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line is inefficient, because it creates a new process every time.  That efficiency hit may or may not matter to your application.

Also, it's very easy to introduce a security flaw passing command line arguments.  See the warnings in here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Two better solutions:

1. Build a REST API on top of your code and invoke it from your PHP.  Tools like [swagger](http://swagger.io/) make it very easy to generate JSON-packing code, and you'll have a clear definition of your interface.  Also, you can later decide to move the process to another machine.
2. Write a PHP extension.